# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'abort' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I have a problem in my code, a button calls this ajax request from within a jQuery UI dialog

```
myaudioupload = $.ajax({
        url: "some url",
        type: "POST",
        data: formdata,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success: function (data) {
        var data = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
        console.log('json parsed');
            if(data.status==1){
                console.log('status ok');
            }
            else{
                console.log('status not ok');
            }
        }
    });
```

If the user wants to cancel the request, user closes the dialog box and then the following lines are executed:

```
close: function(event, ui) { 
    if(myaudioupload.abort()) {
        console.log('aborted');
        $('#uploadaudioform')[0].reset();
    }}
```

This works fine only when the data is being uploaded, not after the upload succeeds or before the upload is triggred. In these conditions, this message shows up

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'abort' of undefined

I have even tried these ways while aborting:

```
if(myaudioupload!=='undefined' && myaudioupload.abort=='function'){
                        myaudioupload.abort();
                        console.log('aborted');
                        $('#uploadaudioform')[0].reset();
                        }
```

but this also does not work; the same error occurs.

So please help me how should i do this or if something is wrong in my code.
Thanks.

Comment: Is `myaudioupload` in the same scope as `close: function(event, ui) {`?

Comment: `myaudioupload!==undefined`...it's not a string, no quotes `' '`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `myaudioupload.abort=='function'` is not a correct way to check property type, use

```
 typeof(myaudioupload.abort)  == 'function' instead.
```

Comment: `typeof` is not a function, no need to use `()`

Comment: Yes, that's why i said no need instead of can not.

Comment: @xdazz Sorry, I misunderstood

Answer (score 3):

Change

`myaudioupload!=='undefined'`

to

```
typeof myaudioupload !== 'undefined'
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ... this helped... i have been going round and round for an hour ...